# SSAS Tabular server has 16 cores, but only 4 are used in queries, at 100% cpu each?

Tags: ssas-tabular

Trying to improve/optimize query response time on a 7gb tabular model, SSAS Tabular 2017.

Server is a VM, has 128gb memory, 8 sockets, 16 cores. No NUMA nodes according to coreinfo.exe.

Biggest table is ~42 million rows, 2nd biggest is ~24 million rows. Query response times are commonly in the 5-15 second range, which seems long to me.

When I run queries against my model from local excel, cores 0-3 peg at 100% while the others remain at 0-ish.

Is this core utilization pattern normal? Should I be looking into server settings that can distribute query work over ALL the cores? Where are such settings?

Comment: Are you using standard or enterprise edition? I'm not sure that explains it but it may be a clue

Comment: Can you look at server properties in SSMS, find the LogDir setting and go to that directory? Then open the msmdsrv.log file and post the logging from the most recent restart of the service here?

Answer (score 1):

In Tabular there are two query execution engines: Formula Engine is single-threaded (used for sophisticated calculations), Storage Engine is multi-threaded (used for simple calculations). From what you say it looks like the queries you run are not optimized to take advantage of Storage Engine. Please look for an article on how queries are executed in Tabular on www.sqlbi.com. Hope this helps anyone.